# c program if else if statement

Tags: c, if-statement

facing problem in second and third else if statement. when i run the code it shows the printf statements of first if and first else if statement except for its own printf statements.how to solve it please help anyone

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{
int sci_score, maths_score;

printf("enter your sci score:", sci_score);

scanf("%d", &sci_score);

printf("enter your maths score:", maths_score);

scanf("%d", &maths_score);

if(sci_score>=33, maths_score>=33) 
{
    printf("you are awarded with ruppees 45");
}

else if(sci_score>=33, maths_score<33)
{
    printf("you are awarded with ruppees 15. work hard in maths");
}

else if(sci_score<33, maths_score>=33)
{
    printf("you are awarded with ruppees 15. work hard in sci");
}

else if(sci_score<33, maths_score<33) 
{
    printf("work hard in sci and maths");
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Do you mean `if(sci_score>=33 && maths_score>=33)` instead of `if(sci_score>=33, maths_score>=33)`? Notice that your code is equivalent to `if(maths_score>=33)`, the expression before the comma is evaluated but does nothing.

Comment: if we add && this is used to seperate two statements instead of a comma(,) ?

Comment: `&&` is the logical AND operator.

Comment: yes, a logical AND operator enforces the statement to make sure both statements before and after the && are true and only then the inner block code is executed else not, if you want to bypass this and you want to check if only 1 out of 2 or more conditions become true then you just use the OR operator || which looks for any one condition within the if/else if statement to be true to execute the inner block code

Comment: Where did you get this `if` syntax from?

Comment: printf("enter your sci score:", sci_score);
printf("enter your maths score:", maths_score);
You don't need sci_score & maths_score in your printf statement.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is remove the comma `,` in your if/else if statement and replace with `&&` this means both the conditions in the if/else if block needs to be true for this specific condition to display the print statement,

**Updated Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{
int sci_score, maths_score;

printf("enter your sci score:", sci_score);

scanf("%d", &sci_score);

printf("enter your maths score:", maths_score);

scanf("%d", &maths_score);

if(sci_score>=33 && maths_score>=33) 
{
    printf("you are awarded with ruppees 45");
}

else if(sci_score>=33 && maths_score<33)
{
    printf("you are awarded with ruppees 15. work hard in maths");
}

else if(sci_score<32 && maths_score>=33)
{
    printf("you are awarded with ruppees 15. work hard in sci");
}

else if(sci_score<33 && maths_score<33) 
{
    printf("work hard in sci and maths");
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `&&` operator to match the conditions

```
int main()

{
int sci_score, maths_score;

printf("enter your sci score:", sci_score);

scanf("%d", &sci_score);

printf("enter your maths score:", maths_score);

scanf("%d", &maths_score);

if(sci_score>=33 && maths_score>=33) 
{
    printf("you are awarded with ruppees 45");
}

else if(sci_score>=33 && maths_score<33)
{
    printf("you are awarded with ruppees 15. work hard in maths");
}

else if(sci_score<33 && maths_score>=33)
{
    printf("you are awarded with ruppees 15. work hard in sci");
}

else if(sci_score<33 && maths_score<33) 
{
    printf("work hard in sci and maths");
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm borrowing your words here, you need to word hard on understanding C operators first. What you are trying to do for each `if || else if` statement is to satisfy both score conditions, which require logical operators.

But you are using comma operator, which is very rarely used in C. I actually never use it and have to look it up after reading your question. Because I could not understand at first why your program still compiled. Guess I also need to work on this too.